# how to set up MAT in eclipse SDK

Tags: eclipse, memory, memory-leaks, mat

I am new to eclipse and MAT how can i set up MAT in eclipse

Regards,
Kariyachan

Comment: I am not googling for MAT, what is it?

Comment: @leppie thanks for the reply,MAT- eclipse memory analyzer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you talking about Eclipse Memory Analyzer  then,

This is it. from Vogella  http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html